Helm template doesn't support dotted yaml values
I'm trying to obtain a compact values.yaml version for my charts, but helm template doesn't apply dotted values as I (wrongly?) expected.
To be clear:
"classic notation":
first:
  second:
    third: 4

Dotted notation:
first.second.third: 4

base-values:
my-service:
  replicaCount: 1

values-file-1
my-service.replicaCount: 2

values-file-2
my-service:
  replicaCount: 2

Using values-file-2 gives me proper values substitution, while values-file-1 leaves original base-values.

Those files are different.  Your base-values file has a key my-service, whose value is a map, with a single key replicaCount; your values-file-1 has a flat map with a single key my-service.replicaCount.  Do you expect one to match the other, and if so, why?

Since the values file defines the overrides of base chart values, I'd expect to use a valid yaml notation to place those values. Since the --set option supports dotted notation, and dotted notation, as well as json notation are valid yaml notations to crawl the chart structure, I'd expect it to work. I assume that using directly gotemplating brings it's constraints, though.

The two files you show are different.  There is not a general YAML rule that dotted syntax is equivalent to nested-map syntax.  You need to make the actual structures of the files match.
YAML syntax is very similar to JSON syntax (and indeed valid JSON is also valid YAML), and it might help to recast these structures into their JSON equivalent to more explicitly show the map structure:
{
  "my-service": {
    "replicaCount": 1
  }
}

{
  "my-service.replicaCount": 1
}

The two objects have different keys and different structures, and one will not replace the other.
helm install --set has a unique syntax.  The various things it specifies, including dotted paths and setting array-type values, only work with the --set option; they are not generic YAML syntax.
You'll also see these differences in writing the templates.  .Values.a.b looks up things in a nested map; you need to use something like index .Values "a.b" to find keys with dots in their names.
If you're just trying to pack things into fewer lines, YAML does have single-line forms for most data structures, and it would work to say
my-service: { replicaCount: 1 }

or, in your leading example,
first: { second: { third: 4 } }

